# JRebel updating changes not tomcat maven plugin

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven, maven-3, jrebel

I have Maven module with JRebel and Tomcat-maven-plugin. I run the tomcat:run with JRebel as shown in the screenshot. Whenever I change are reflected in the browser.

**Question 1:** How do I make sure that these changes are reflected by JRebel not tomcat redeployment like in Jetty plugin we make 0?

[image]

**In Console**

```
[2012-09-17 10:11:22] JRebel: Directory 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Java\IntelliJ-Projects\Struts2_Maven_HelloWorld\target\classes' will be monitored for changes.
[2012-09-17 10:11:22] JRebel: Directory 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Java\IntelliJ-Projects\Struts2_Maven_HelloWorld\src\main\webapp' will be monitored for changes.
```

**Question 2:** Is there any way to enable JRebel logging with -Drebel.log=true in pom.xml JRebel plugin. I am unable to enable logging.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is redeployed by Tomcat, it looses the session. So you will start over from the first screen (login into the app again) if that the case. The plugin itself only defines *reload* and *redeploy* goals, which do not seem to trigger automatically anyway.

OR you can try the following config

```
            <configuration>
                <update>true</update>
            </configuration>
```

To enable JRebel logging, you can pass the **-Drebel.log=true** argument via MAVEN_OPTS environment variable (just a wild guess). Or you can specify the VM arguments in Runner tab for the Run configuration:

[image: Maven Run confugration]

Comment: thanks. I should use <update>false</update> to stop tomcat from updating if it is. right?

Comment: hopefully so, since there do not seem to be any other parameters that could be capable for this